# Floating side by side

Tags: html, css

I want to float the following codes side by side from each other responsively. How can I do that?

[image]

Here's are the HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/free-membership-300x188.jpg" alt="free-membership" width="300" height="188" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14074" /> 

<h3>Today’s Price: 100% FREE</h3>
<p><strong>ONLINE VIDEO COURSE</strong></p>
<p><strong>Availability</strong>: Immediate Access in Members Area</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary">GET ACCESS NOW</button>

<img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/satisfaction-guaranteed-300x300.png" alt="satisfaction-guaranteed" width="300" height="300" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14075" />


You can get started right now, in this moment, to shift your life to a more powerful, more accountable life! We offer a free video series that shares insights into the mindset of a victim, the characteristics and verbiage victims unknowingly use, and some steps and tools to live a more accountable life! 

We also clarify some of the misconceptions of accountability and why it is that for many, accountability is something that is avoided, when in truth, it is the key to a more free, powerful fulfilling life!!!
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.right{
float: right;
}

.left{
float: left;
}
```

And here's the jSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/6totya08/

Comment: Are you expecting us to write the CSS for you? Because there was no CSS when I went to that fiddle.

Comment: Using bootstrap easily you can achieve this.

Comment: How can I do that on JSFIDDLE?

Answer (score 0):

Using `bootstrap` you can easily achieve this kind of responsive design.

```
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/free-membership-300x188.jpg" alt="free-membership" width="300" height="188" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14074" /> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <h3>Today’s Price: 100% FREE</h3>
     <p><strong>ONLINE VIDEO COURSE</strong></p>
     <p><strong>Availability</strong>: Immediate Access in Members Area</p>
     <button class="btn btn-primary">GET ACCESS NOW</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/satisfaction-guaranteed-300x300.png" alt="satisfaction-guaranteed" width="300" height="300" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14075" />
   </div>

 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        You can get started right now, in this moment, to shift your life to a more powerful, more accountable life! We offer a free video series that shares insights into the mindset of a victim, the characteristics and verbiage victims unknowingly use, and some steps and tools to live a more accountable life! 
       We also clarify some of the misconceptions of accountability and why it is that for many, accountability is something that is avoided, when in truth, it is the key to a more free, powerful fulfilling life!!!
   </div>
 </div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/6totya08/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each group of content in a div, let's call it `col`. Then, you need to specify width and float for each one.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="col">
      // your content here
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      // your content here
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      // your content here
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6totya08/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Now **create three section** and `define` `display` property

```
 table-cell
```

HI now change your html and css as like this

```css
.leftSec, .rightSec, .centerSec{display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;}
.centerSec{text-align:center;}
.leftSec img, .rightSec img{width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="leftSec">
<img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/free-membership-300x188.jpg" alt="free-membership" class=" alignnone size-medium wp-image-14074" /> 
</div>
<div class="centerSec">
<h3>Today’s Price: 100% FREE</h3>
<p><strong>ONLINE VIDO COURSE</strong></p>
<p><strong>Availability</strong>: Immediate Access in Members Area</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary">GET ACCESS NOW</button>

</div>

<div class="rightSec">
<img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/satisfaction-guaranteed-300x300.png" alt="satisfaction-guaranteed" class=" alignnone size-medium wp-image-14075" />

</div>

<div class="container">


You can get started right now, in this moment, to shift your life to a more powerful, more accountable life! We offer a free video series that shares insights into the mindset of a victim, the characteristics and verbiage victims unknowingly use, and some steps and tools to live a more accountable life! 

We also clarify some of the misconceptions of accountability and why it is that for many, accountability is something that is avoided, when in truth, it is the key to a more free, powerful fulfilling life!!!

<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap for responsive like below work on your images so that they will scale to the resolution you can refer below code for reference

https://jsfiddle.net/gauravj/6totya08/5/

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="col-xs-12">

<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/free-membership-300x188.jpg" alt="free-membership" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14074" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<h3>Today’s Price: 100% FREE</h3>
<p><strong>ONLINE VIDEO COURSE</strong></p>
<p><strong>Availability</strong>: Immediate Access in Members Area</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary">GET ACCESS NOW</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
<img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/satisfaction-guaranteed-300x300.png" alt="satisfaction-guaranteed" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14075" />
</div>


<div class="col-xs-12">
You can get started right now, in this moment, to shift your life to a more powerful, more accountable life! We offer a free video series that shares insights into the mindset of a victim, the characteristics and verbiage victims unknowingly use, and some steps and tools to live a more accountable life! 

We also clarify some of the misconceptions of accountability and why it is that for many, accountability is something that is avoided, when in truth, it is the key to a more free, powerful fulfilling life!!!
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
check this
```

```css
.row{float:left;width:100%;padding-bottom:20px;}
.col-3{float:left;width:33.3%;padding:0 15px;box-sizing:border-box}
.col-3 img{width:100%;height:auto}
```

```html
<div class="row"><div class="col-3"><img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/free-membership-300x188.jpg" alt="free-membership" width="300" height="188" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14074" /> </div>
<div class="col-3">
<h3>Today’s Price: 100% FREE</h3>
<p><strong>ONLINE VIDEO COURSE</strong></p>
<p><strong>Availability</strong>: Immediate Access in Members Area</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary">GET ACCESS NOW</button>
</div><div class="col-3">
<img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/satisfaction-guaranteed-300x300.png" alt="satisfaction-guaranteed" width="300" height="300" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14075" />
</div>
</div>
You can get started right now, in this moment, to shift your life to a more powerful, more accountable life! We offer a free video series that shares insights into the mindset of a victim, the characteristics and verbiage victims unknowingly use, and some steps and tools to live a more accountable life! 

We also clarify some of the misconceptions of accountability and why it is that for many, accountability is something that is avoided, when in truth, it is the key to a more free, powerful fulfilling life!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.left{float:left}
.right{float:right}
.w33{width:33%}
.w32{width:32%; margin: 0 1%}
.clear{clear:both}
```

```html
<div class="left w33">
<img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/free-membership-300x188.jpg" alt="free-membership" width="100%" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14074" /> 
</div>
<div class="left w32">
<h3>Today’s Price: 100% FREE</h3>
<p><strong>ONLINE VIDEO COURSE</strong></p>
<p><strong>Availability</strong>: Immediate Access in Members Area</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary">GET ACCESS NOW</button>
</div>
<div class="right w33">
<img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/satisfaction-guaranteed-300x300.png" alt="satisfaction-guaranteed" width="75%" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14075" />
</div>

<div class="clear">
You can get started right now, in this moment, to shift your life to a more powerful, more accountable life! We offer a free video series that shares insights into the mindset of a victim, the characteristics and verbiage victims unknowingly use, and some steps and tools to live a more accountable life! 

We also clarify some of the misconceptions of accountability and why it is that for
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your HTML and CSS like this. [**Check this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6totya08/12/) if needed

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="cols right-spacing">
<img class="img1" src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/free-membership-300x188.jpg" alt="free-membership" width="300" height="188" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14074" /> 
</div>

<div class="cols right-spacing">
<h3>Today’s Price: 100% FREE</h3>
<p><strong>ONLINE VIDEO COURSE</strong></p>
<p><strong>Availability</strong>: Immediate Access in Members Area</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary">GET ACCESS NOW</button>
</div>

<div class="cols">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/satisfaction-guaranteed-300x300.png" alt="satisfaction-guaranteed" width="300" height="300" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14075" />
</div>

<div class="paragraph">
You can get started right now, in this moment, to shift your life to a more powerful, more accountable life! We offer a free video series that shares insights into the mindset of a victim, the characteristics and verbiage victims unknowingly use, and some steps and tools to live a more accountable life! 

We also clarify some of the misconceptions of accountability and why it is that for many, accountability is something that is avoided, when in truth, it is the key to a more free, powerful fulfilling life!!!
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 100%;  
}

.cols {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.right-spacing {
  margin-right: 5%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.paragraph {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```